# Could you show me how to write this design?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to write this design with HTML and CSS. But my result is not same as the design.

The texts and their backgrounds are not in the right positions. And I think that my HTML element structure is the problem and probably the problem is also in the CSS. Could you show me how can I write the codes to get the result same as the design?

[image: this is my design]

[image: this is my result]

```css
.global_navigation_con {
  display: flex;
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 10px auto 31px;
}

.global_navigation_con div {
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 0px 6px 77px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 0px;
}

.global_navigation_con {
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/300);
}

.global_navigation_con div a {
  font-size: 2.1rem;
  line-height: 2.1rem;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 0px 40px 0px 0px;
}

.global_navigation_con div a span {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.global_navigation_con div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: url(./detail-img/global_list.png) no-repeat;
  width: 22px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 36px;
}
```

```html
<div class="global_navigation_con">
  <div>
    <a href="#"><span>トピックス</span></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#"><span>区画情報</span></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#"><span>立地企業</span></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#"><span>企業支援</span></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#"><span>福知山市と</span><span>その周辺</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) - Can you include the actual background image.

Comment: Thanks for your advice bro. I will try to include the actual background image in the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have redone this and gotten it as close as possible with flex properties. This is also mobile-first. I've also got this **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/r3hab/pen/RwMEvRO)** you can play with.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-direction: column;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  nav ul {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
nav ul li {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #E7E7E7, #FCFCFC);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  position: relative;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  nav ul li {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  nav ul li {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
}

.overlay {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1.2rem;
  top: 0.8rem;
  z-index: 10;
  color: black;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .overlay {
    top: 1.2rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .overlay {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}
.overlay::before {
  font: var(--fa-font-solid);
  content: "";
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  color: #4880B5;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      Topics
      <a href="#" class="overlay">トピックス</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      Section
      <a href="#" class="overlay">区画情報</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      Location
      <a href="#" class="overlay">立地企業</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      Support
      <a href="#" class="overlay">企業支援</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      Unknown
      <a href="#" class="overlay">福知山市と</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I used the idea of your coding in my project and it was helpful bro. Thanks in advance.

Comment: OK bro, I will mark it.

Answer (score -1):

I've made this design with CSS grid to the best of my posibilities. I've scaled the ".grid_wrapper" class down just for stackoverflow purposes, feel free to remove if for your own use.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
}

.grid_container {
    width: 100%;

}

.grid_wrapper {
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 190px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 50px);
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
    grid-row-gap: 60px;
transform: scale(0.8);
}

.grid_item {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #E7E7E7, #EAEAEA, transparent);
    display: flex;
    
}

.grid_item:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

i {
    color: rgb(73, 149, 211);
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
}

.grid_itemtext {
    width:120px;
    font-size: medium;
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: 200;
}

.grid_itemtextback {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.8;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}


@media screen
and (max-device-width: 860px) {
.grid_wrapper {
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 150px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 60px);
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
    grid-row-gap: 5px;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="grid_container">
        <div class="grid_wrapper">
        <div class="grid_item"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i><h1 class="grid_itemtext">トピックス</h1><h2 class="grid_itemtextback">Topics</h2></div>
        <div class="grid_item"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i><h1 class="grid_itemtext">区画情報</h1><h2 class="grid_itemtextback">Section</h2></div>
        <div class="grid_item"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i><h1 class="grid_itemtext">立地企業</h1><h2 class="grid_itemtextback">Location</h2></div>
        <div class="grid_item"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i><h1 class="grid_itemtext">企業支援</h1><h2 class="grid_itemtextback">Support</h2></div>
        <div class="grid_item"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i><h1 class="grid_itemtext">福知山市と</h1><h2 class="grid_itemtextback">Are</h2></div>
        <div class="grid_item"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i><h1 class="grid_itemtext">その周辺</h1><h2 class="grid_itemtextback">English</h2></div>
        <div class="grid_item"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i><h1 class="grid_itemtext">その周辺</h1><h2 class="grid_itemtextback">English</h2></div>
        <div class="grid_item"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i><h1 class="grid_itemtext">その周辺</h1><h2 class="grid_itemtextback">English</h2></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't match the original design.

Comment: although this doesn't match the design I will try to test your idea for my projects. Thank you for your answer.